# Composer curl error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, ssl, curl, composer-php

I'm working with Symfony 5 and I need to install 'knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle' with composer but I have this message:

```txt
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

please help me

I tried to add cacert.pem into my php.ini with

```txt
curl.cainfo ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
```

I tried to disable the verify_peer in my composer.json and nothing is working.

this is my composer diag :

```txt
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.composer/package-versions-deprecated : exact version constraints (1.11.99.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning

Checking platform settings: OK

Checking git settings: OK

Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Checking disk free space: OK

Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK

Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Composer version: 2.0.13
PHP version: 7.3.21
PHP binary path: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
cURL version: 7.70.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1g
zip: extension present, unzip present
```

please help me

---

may be my composer config have a problem

```html
"config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "options": {
            "ssl": {
                "verify_peer": false,
                "allow_self_signed": false,
                "cafile": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/extras/ssl/cacert.pem",
                "local_cert": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
            }
        }

    },
```

Comment: The problem statement is _"self signed certificate in certificate chain"_ and the configuration is `"allow_self_signed": false,` - Have you tried to allow self-signed for a test? What happens if you do? Are you fine with just getting rid of the error message or do you have further requirements with the certificate chain?

Comment: Compare as well: https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/373 and https://www.reddit.com/r/Snipe_IT/comments/o4vbcn/error_when_running_compose_update/

Comment: I think I have found the solutions. When I write "ping google.com" in my cmd I have no connection. So I m talking with the network team for this . Thanks you so mutch for your help

Comment: Ask them if they are doing ssl decryption. You may need to exclude this URL.

Comment: Ok I will ask them thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

This configuration option: `allow_self_signed` comes from nowhere, it has no effect; It doesn't even appear in the documentation of composer.

I lost hours of precious time due to this misleading option.

If you have a similar problem I would recommend to use the latest version of PHP (that meets your requirements, obviously) and the latest composer version, etc. Works for me, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and changed the `composer.json` to use `HTTP` instead of default `HTTPS` by adding below snippet.
It's not a good practice, don't use it unless you really have no choice.

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "packagist": false
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://repo.packagist.org/"
    }
]
```

I've put in in parent directory of the directory that I was trying to install laravel in it.